# How to run Selenium C# tests on Command Prompt?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, command-prompt

I have some C# tests, and I want to run these tests from Command Prompt.

How can I run these tests?

Please help me.

Comment: With what framework? MSTest? NUnit? Is it being run as a console app? A web app? A WinForms app? A WPF app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Visual Studio 2012**, then you will use `vstest.console.exe` to run the tests like Visual Studio, for example:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe UnitTests.dll /logger:trx`

The VSTest.Console.exe documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155796.aspx).

Otherwise, you will use `mstest` on the command line if **Visual Studio 2010**:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe`

The MSTest.exe documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx).

The same applies when running **Selenium** tests; there is nothing special about them as far as running from the command line is concerned.

Comment: I appreciate that note at the end about Selenium tests. I thought they were going to be far more difficult to set-up.