# MsTest.exe not finding any tests

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest, specflow

I have a selenium Specflow c# project in which I can execute tests from the test explorer and via the ReSharper unit test explorer.

But when I run the command line to execute tests (This is how Jenkins execute tests)

It does not find any tests in the DLL

```
mstest /testcontainer:MoneyUITests.dll /test:NavigateToLoans
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26621.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading MoneyUITests.dll...
Test NavigateToLoans cannot be found.
Test NavigateToLoans cannot be found.
Starting execution...
No tests to execute.
```

Not sure what I have done wrong, it seems strange that visual studio managed to find and execute the tests with no issue.

Comment: 1 solution.. drop any ms/vsTest and use nUnit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because mstest.exe was used for testing in Visual Studio 2010
Since Visual Studio 2012 you should use VSTest.Console.exe.

Have you tried using VSTest.Console.exe instead of mstest.exe?

I found this answer already on stackoverflow: [Answer on How to run selenium c# test in command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18698608/5620792)